# Create a $4\times 4$ matrix A with eigenvectors [1 1 1 1] and [1 0 1 0] and eigenvalues 1, 1, 2, 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Does anyone have a nice way to create a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ that has eigenvectors
$$\vec v_1=\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr 1\cr 1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\vec v_2=\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}$$
and eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$? The eigenvalues both have algebraic multiplicity 2.

I'm looking for a method that I can use repeatedly; that is, suppose I want to find a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ with eigenvectors 
$$\vec v_1=\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr 1\cr 2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\vec v_2=\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\vec v_3=\pmatrix{-1\cr 1\cr 1\cr 1}$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=1$, and $\lambda_3=2$, where the algebraic multiplicities are 1, 1, and 2.

Again, I don't just want answer for these specific examples, but a process that I can use repeatedly, say to find a $5\times 5$ matrix $A$ with 3 eigenvectors and 3 eigenvalues, one of algebraic multiplicity 1, the second with algebraic multiplicity 2, and the third with algebraic multiplicity 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a non-singular matrix, s.t. $v_1, v_2 \in \text{im} P$, for example
$$
P = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
Let $B$ be a Jordan matrix of $A$:
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
A = PBP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 1 & 3 & -2 \\
-1 & 2 & 1 & -1 \\
-3 & 1 & 5 & -2 \\
-2 & 1 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

It's important that first and third column of $P$ correspond to the beginnings of Jordan blocks in $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice response. What does imP mean?

Comment: @David it's image of $P$, vector subspace spanned by columns of $P$, or the set $\{Pv : v\in \mathbb R^4\}$. All these are the same.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have nice link to an easy Jordan matrix tutorial?

Comment: Not in English, but Wikipedia article is quite comprehensible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form